# Is my graphics card being used and if so why doesn't it show as VGA compatible controller?

Tags: nvidia

Ubuntu 14.04 here, installed the nvidia drivers. I run lspci and this is what i get:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 0b)    
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)    
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 0b)    
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP USB xHCI HC (rev 04)    
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP HECI #0 (rev 04)    
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP HD Audio Controller (rev 04)    
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev e4)

00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev e4)    
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)    
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 04)    
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)    
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP SMBus Controller (rev 04)    
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)    
02:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce 840M] (rev a2)
```

I must say in BIOS for graphics device I use "discrete" and not "UMA only". And when I look in the nvidia x server settings it says that it is being utilized at a certain % when i watch videos and stuff.

**My question is**

Is my nvidia graphics card being utilized or not? 
If yes, why does my system show vga compatible controller as being the intel graphics controller?
If not, how do I enable the nvidia graphics card?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're running in "Hybrid" mode: *both the NVidia and Intel controller are working!*

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)    
02:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce 840M] (rev a2)
```

So if the PC isn't doing any anti-aliasing or 3D work, only the Intel card is being used.  Once you start watching videos or gaming (not talking about Tetris, but about an advanced 3D-game) you'll see the NVidia Utilisation shoot up!

So: you're fine; perfect job!  Don't break anything!  [Take a system backup...](https://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc)  **;-)**

**Some background info:**
Here's the output of my computer `lshw -c video` when my BIOS graphics setting is set to <kbd>IGD</kbd>: (Integrated Graphics adapter)

```
*-display               
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 07
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
   resources: irq:44 memory:f4000000-f43fffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:1800(size=8)
```

and here after setting it to <kbd>NVidia</kbd>:

```
*-display               
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: G96M [GeForce 9600M GT]
   vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   version: a1
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0
   resources: irq:46 memory:f2000000-f2ffffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:f0000000-f1ffffff ioport:2000(size=128)
```

and `lspci` now gives:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation G96M [GeForce 9600M GT] (rev a1)
```

*So it's pretty clear from your settings that both cards are both doing what they do best individually, depending on your demands...*

Comment: i know how to show my appreciation...if you know what i mean =)))) thanks bro