# Replacing Nouveau driver with Nvidia driver

Tags: drivers, apt, nvidia, graphics, lubuntu

I am running a fresh install of Lubuntu 14.04, and I want to use Nvidia drivers rather than the default Nouveau drivers.

So, as advised here (http://www.binarytides.com/install-nvidia-drivers-ubuntu-14-04/), I enter the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa -y
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

This appears to run fine. However, if I check the installation by entering:

```
lspci -vnn | grep -i VGA -A 12
```

Then I get the output:

```
Kernel driver in use: nouveau
```

So it seems that the Nouveau driver is still being run, rather than the Nvidia driver. How do I enable the Nvidia driver?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install the Nvidia drivers?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers)

Comment: In Ubuntu there is an option in system settings to install proptietary drivers. Its just click and go. See if you have a package called 'jockey' in your repos, I think thats the program for installing drivers.

Comment: After you add the repository, you have to run sudo apt-get update, then try the install.  What Nvidia card/chip do you have?

Comment: recommend anybody else finding this answer should review this Q answer:

Install Nvidia driver instead of nouveau
https://askubuntu.com/questions/481414/install-nvidia-driver-instead-of-nouveau

Answer (score 0):

Try running "sudo ubuntu-drivers devices".  With older versions you need jockey-text.  "sudo jockey-text -e xorg:nvidia_current"

Answer (score 0):

You might be in hybrid mode, see this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/580961/is-my-graphics-card-being-used-and-if-so-why-doesnt-it-show-as-vga-compatible-c) vga output will remain that way. I think you should do:

```
lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 3D
sudo apt-get install glmark2
glmark2
```

Answer (score 0):

recommend anybody else finding this answer should review this Q & answer:

Install Nvidia driver instead of nouveau
[Install Nvidia driver instead of nouveau](https://askubuntu.com/questions/481414/install-nvidia-driver-instead-of-nouveau)